# removing duplicates from a column R

Tags: r, unique, substr

I have a column with list of Ids with varying length where some of the Ids have version numbers.

```
rownames(x)

"ENSP00000424360.1-D4"
"ENSP00000424360.2-D4"
"ENSP00000424360.3-D4"
"ENSP00000437781-D59"
"XP_010974537.1"
"XP_010974538.1"
"XP_010974538.2"
```

I want these to be changed into:

```
"ENSP00000424360"
"ENSP00000424360.1"
"ENSP00000424360.2"
"ENSP00000437781"
"XP_010974537"
"XP_010974538"
"XP_010974538.1"
```

I can convert `ENSxx` or `XPxx` individually using

```
make.unique(substr(rownames(x),1,15))
```

or

```
make.unique(substr(rownames(dds),1,12))
```

How can I change the code to get desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We remove the substring with `sub` and apply the `make.unique`

```
make.unique(sub("-.*$", "", sub("\\..*", "", rownames(x))))
#[1] "ENSP00000424360"   "ENSP00000424360.1" "ENSP00000424360.2"
#[4] "ENSP00000437781"   "XP_010974537"      "XP_010974538"      "XP_010974538.1"
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(v1 = 1:7), .Names = "v1", row.names = c("ENSP00000424360.1-D4", 
 "ENSP00000424360.2-D4", "ENSP00000424360.3-D4", "ENSP00000437781-D59", 
 "XP_010974537.1", "XP_010974538.1", "XP_010974538.2"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am sorry but I had mistake in my question (output section). Now I have edited it.